# script checking file exists

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make script which will check if file exists. Filename is passed by argument. The script is  checking if file exists in current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=$(find $1)
failure="find: ‘$1‘: No such file or directory"

if [ "$tmp" != "$failure" ]; then
        echo "file exists"
else
        echo "file not exists"
fi
```

I am creating two variables. First one holds result of `find` command, and the second one holds the failure message of `find` command. In `if` statement I am comparing those variables.

Even if file exists I am getting always `else` statement message. 
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `if [[ -e "$1" ]]; then echo "file exists"; else echo "file not exists"; fi`?

Comment: Cult-cargo programming spotted

Comment: Thanks to read doc : FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ | Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide | Ref: http://gnu.org/s/bash/manual | http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ | http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes | Check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/ And avoid people recommendations saying to learn with tldp.org web site, the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, I hadn't heard that term. That's awesome, I will use it. :-D

Comment: You're welcome @ghoti, with pleasure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `find` in case your file is in current path itself, following may help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
        echo "file exists"
else
        echo "file does not exists"
fi
```

Then run script as `script.ksh file_name` Also in case you need to verify if file exists and is having some size then change `-f` to `-s` in above code.

You could also do `man test` for checking all these kind of conditions too in your box.

Comment: So if statement has its own "commands"?

Comment: @Iomanip, it is like checks you could say, see `man test` for more details.

Comment: `help [[` and no need quoting inside `[[ ]]`

Comment: @Down voter, what is the reason of down vote? I never get a reply to it from down voters :(

Comment: @GillesQuenot Quoting is *sometimes* unneeded inside `[[ ]]`, but sometimes it is needed. For example, in `[[ $a = $b ]]`, the value of `$a` will be treated as a literal string whether it's quoted or not, but the value of `$b` will be treated as a  glob pattern unless it's quoted. IMO it's easier to just double-quote all variable expansions than to keep track of where it's safe to leave the quotes off.